# Dual Ascent Method (DAM)

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I recently came across the dual ascent method. The method is part of my question so it is written formally below.
$$\min_{x} (f(x))\hspace{1cm}subject\hspace{1mm}to\hspace{1mm}Ax = b $$
The Lagrangian is $$L(x, y) = f(x) + y
^\intercal(Ax − b)$$
the dual function $$g(y) = \inf_{x} (L(x, y))$$ and the dual problem $$\max_{y}(g(y))$$, where y is the dual variable.
One method that gives us this solution is the Dual Ascent Method (DAM), characterized at iteration k by computing until convergence: 
$$1.\hspace{1mm} x^{k+1} := \arg min_x(L(x, y^{k+1})) (minimization \hspace{1mm}for\hspace{1mm} f(x) \hspace{1mm}on\hspace{1mm} x)$$
$$2.\hspace{1mm} y^{k+1} := y^{k} + α^{k}(Ax^{k+1} − b) \hspace{1mm}(update\hspace{1mm}y \hspace{1mm}for \hspace{1mm}next\hspace{1mm} iteration)$$
It may be a easy question but my doubt is how to actually perform the minimization in step 1 is it using partial derivative?

Comment: It depends on the problem we are solving. The best method to use in step 1 will depend on what structure $f$ has. But the problem in step 1 is unconstrained, so we can hope that it is an easy problem. An important observation is that if $f$ is separable, then the problem in step 1 is separable, so it can be solved in parallel.

Comment: thanks for your clarification. can you share me links for some sample worked out problems so that I can understand it better?

Comment: What is $\alpha^k$ in point 2? How is it updated?